# rails plugin for twitter, facebook and openID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, ruby-on-rails-plugins

Is there a rails plugin which can handle authentication with facebook, twitter and openID providers (ex. google, yahoo...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise).  It is a very active project that is maintained by José Valim who is a contributor to Rails core.  I've been using it for several months for authentication with both Facebook and Google (through openid) without any real problems.

Answer (score 0):

authlogic with authlogic_oauth & authlogic_facebook_connect will cover all of those.